# python string comparison not working

Tags: python

The following fabric code returns

```
root@vm101:~# cat fabfile.py
import fabric
def lsb_info():
    ReleaseNum=fabric.api.local('lsb_release --release|awk \'{print $2}\'', capture=True)
    print ReleaseNum == 12.04
    print ReleaseNum


root@vm101:~# fab lsb_info
[localhost] local: lsb_release --release|awk '{print $2}'
False
12.04
```

Eventhough the ReleaseNum is populated as 12.04 it is not equalling 12.04 in the string comparison

Comment: You should probably use quotes around it : `"12.04"`, otherwise it will be considered a float object.

Comment: The main issue aside, it feels really odd to be using `awk` from a Python script like this...

Comment: Yes ..question was part of that adventure

Comment: see my answer to speed up your _adventure_..

Answer (score 1):

Because `12.04` is a float and not a string, add quotes to it, like so:

```
print ReleaseNum == '12.04'
```

Since `ReleaseNum` is a string, when you compare it with `12.04` it returns false, because they're of different types, so when you convert `12.04` to a string by putting quotes, it works...